# Is this effect on Thor real or is it CGI?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, effects, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* we learn that, after the events of *Infinity War*

> Thor became an alcoholic and got really, really fat

It is difficult to get an image of this, but this [spoiler image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2MO5.jpg) should be enough. We see Thor like this throughout the entire movie.

Is it CGI or did Chris Hemsworth get like that for the role?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly CGI or padding, I doubt Chris got fat for the role. In fact he is his normal self on the red carpet for *Endgame*. And looking through his posts on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/chrishemsworth/?hl=en) he is never fat.

[image]

Comment: Probably CGI indeed but for the record that could've been achieved with paddings as well

Comment: @Jenayah True, clarified. I just meant it wasn't Chris getting fat.

Answer (score 3):

Joe Russo's words from [bgr.com](https://bgr.com/2019/04/30/avengers-endgame-ending-russo-brothers-on-captain-america-iron-man/)

> Q: Why did you make Thor fat? Did Chris also become fat for the role or it was done through CG?
>
> A: It was mostly CG'd. Thor suffered more loss than anyone else, he has been living in constant pain and regret.

Answer (score 2):

This was primarily achieved with a 60-70 lb fat suit to add on the additional bulk and get the actor to walk and move about with the weight that would look natural on camera. Hair and makeup also did a convincing job of making his face looked puffed for the fat Thor role, and I assume they touched it up with CGI afterward to blend it all together(unsourced).

video source: [Avengers: Endgame - "Bro Thor" Behind the Scenes Fat Suit Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WFftaupCMU)